# Python key error in inserting

Tags: python

I am facing a problem in inserting operation on dictionary as given here in the code

**input format**

no. of operations to be performed in first line then, the operations to be  performed

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                            
File "solution.py", line 25, in <module>        
arr.insert(cmd[j])    
KeyError: ('1', '10')
```

**Inputs**

```
2    
insert 0 5    
print
```

**CODE**

```
       arr = list()

       cmd = dict()


     num = int(raw_input())

     for i in range(0,num):

         command = str(raw_input())
         command = command.split(" ")

         if(len(command) == 2):
             cmd[command[0]] = command[1]

         if(len(command) == 3 ):
             cmd[command[0]] = command[1],command[2]



   for i,j in cmd.items():

       if(i == "insert"):
           arr.insert(cmd[j])

       if(i == "append"):
           arr.append(cmd[j])

       if(i == "remove"):
           arr.remove(cmd[j])

       if(i == "pop"):
           arr.pop(cmd[j])

       if(i == "sort"):
           arr.sort()

       if(i == "index"):
           print arr.index(cmd[j])

       if(i == "count"):
           print arr.count(cmd[j])

       if(i=="print"):
           print arr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
     if(len(command) == 3 ):
         cmd[command[0]] = command[1],command[2]
```

a tuple `(command[1],command[2])` is inserted in the dictionnary `cmd`.

Then, you sent the whole tuple as index parameter for the `insert` method:

```
   if(i == "insert"):
       arr.insert(cmd[j])
```

You should probably unpack it before, using first argument as index and second as object:

```
   if(i == "insert"):
       arr.insert(*cmd[j])
```

or, more verbose:

```
   if(i == "insert"):
       index, obj = cmd[j]
       arr.insert(index, obj)
```

Comment: you should consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), if it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry,I badly want to vote your answer but,I don't have the reputation

Comment: However, you can *accept* it, because you have asked the question. The gray mark, as shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/XgH04Em.png), is clickable.